# How to maximize the infinity norm over a convex region?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research, non-convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization model

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\max_{i \in S} |x_{i}|\\ \text{subject to} & Q(x)+ \displaystyle\sum_{i \in S}|x_{i}| \leq m\end{array}$$

where $x_{i} \in \mathbb R$, $Q(x)$ denotes a quadratic function of $x$, and $m$ is a known number.

Can we write this model as a quadratic and convex optimization model, which can be solved by optimization solvers such as Gurobi or CPLEX? In particular, how should we deal with a $\max \max$ type optimization problem?

Comment: Yes. it is. Added to my question.

Comment: Okay. You’re _maximizing_ a convex function, so this is going to require the introduction of binary/integer variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be equivalently stated as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\ &\|x\|_\infty\\
\text{s.t.}\ & x^{T}Ax+b^{T}x+\|x\|_1\leqslant{c}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
for some symmetric positive-definite matrix $A$. The constraint is convex, but since you are *maximizing* a convex function, this is a hard problem (NP hard, I believe). Consequently, to solve it, we will have to introduce some binary/integer variables.

Essentially, there are two things you need to be able to do:

1. Model the absolute values--*i.e.* introduce variables $y_i\geqslant0$ such that $y_i=|x_i|$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. This is equivalent to enforcing that \begin{equation} 
   |x_i|\leqslant{y_i}\Leftrightarrow -y_i\leqslant x_i\leqslant y_i\ \text{ for all }i=1,\dots,n,
   \end{equation}
   which is easy, *and* that $y_i\leqslant|x_i|$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. This will require two things: (1) a value $u_i>0$ such that $|x_i|\leqslant u_i$ holds for all $x$ in which we are interested, and (2) introducing a binary variable $z_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$ such that $z_i=1$ iff $x_i\geqslant0$. Using (1) and (2), we have that 
   \begin{equation}
   y_i\leqslant |x_i| \Leftrightarrow y_i\leqslant x_i+2u_i(1-z_i)\text{ and }y_i\leqslant -x_i+2u_iz_i.
   \end{equation}
   In your case, assumption (1) is basically equivalent to having an upper bound on the optimal objective value. In principle, you could just "pick a huge number", but this is inadvisable--the larger the values $u_i$ are chosen, the weaker the continuous relaxation of this problem becomes, the harder it becomes to solve. Try to pick smart values of $u_i$.
2. Model the maximum. This is outlined [in the Gurobi documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:GeneralConstraints), for example. From the link:

> For example, the MAX constraint $r = \max\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,c\}$ can be modeled as follows:
>   \begin{equation} 
> \begin{array}{rcll}
> r &=& x_i+s_j &\text{ for all }j=1,\dots,k\\
> r &=& c+s_{k+1} & \\
> z_1+\dots+z_{k+1} &=& 1 & \\
> SOS1(s_j,z_j) && & \text{ for all }j=1,\dots,k+1\\
> s_j &\geqslant& 0 & \text{ for all }j=1,\dots,k+1\\
> z_j &\in& \{0,1\} & \text{ for all }j=1,\dots,k+1
> \end{array}
> \end{equation}
>   The first two constraints state that $r \geq \max\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,c\}$, i.e., that the resultant variable $r$ has to be at least as large as each of the operand variables $x_j$ and the constant $c$. This can be modeled using inequalities, but we turned them into equations by introducing explicit continuous slack variables $s_j \geq 0$, which we will reuse below.
>
> Those slack variables and the remaining constraints model $r \leq \max\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,c\}$, which is more complicated. In addition to the explicit slacks, this requires the introduction of binary auxiliary variables $z_j \in \{0,1\}$. The SOS1 constraints state that at most one of the two variables $s_j$ and $z_j$ can be non-zero, which models the implication $z_j = 1 \rightarrow s_j = 0$. Due to the third constraint, one $z_j$ will be equal to $1$ and thus at least one $s_j$ will be zero. Hence, $r = x_j$ for at least one $j$ due to the first constraint, or $r = c$ due to the second constraint.

This should be sufficient detail to figure this out for yourself.

### Note on Gurobi

If you want to solve this with Gurobi, as you stated, then you should take advantage of Gurobi's [general constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:GeneralConstraints). General constraints automatically handle both of the reformulations above, and hide all the messy details from you. In combination with their support for [quadratic constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:QuadraticConstraints), you should be well on your way to solving.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I accept it as a correct one.